# he has plowed about $127 million into hotels -- meaning?

Tags: meaning

> For him, as for many, the Ukraine disaster has just added a wholly unwelcome extra layer of uncertainty over his diverse businesses. He estimates he has **plowed** about $127 million over the past decade **into** hotels in Crimea.

How do you understand that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [Macmillan](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/us/dictionary/american/plow-into):

> *Plow something into something*: to invest a lot of money in something in order to improve it or make it successful

Comment: This usage is analogous to planting seeds in a field, in hopes that they will produce a valuable crop later.  In most annual crops (like grains and vegetables) the planting process includes plowing (to aerate the soil, shape the ground for good drainage, and kill weeds), fertilizing, killing weeds, and planting.  It is a huge investment, with a likely -- but not guaranteed -- return later in the year.

Answer (score 0):

It's a metaphor. Think of a snow plow. You can push large quantities of snow into one big pile. So if you invest a lot of resources -- money, time, whatever -- into something, we say you have "plowed money into this business" or "plowed time into this theory" or whatever. The idea is that you've invested an extraordinary amount, so it's either wasteful or it's such a huge project that it requires huge resources, depending on the context.